# react render called before componentdidmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

In my componentDidMount() I am making an API call "invokeservice" to fetch some data, this call then sets a state object that I use in my render.

The problem I am having is that the invokeservice is not being called and set the first time that the page is loaded, however when I refresh the page the invokeservice returns the data fine and the rest of the script will run. It's only the first time that it returns an null value.

Is it possible to call this invoke service in render function and keep the data ready and display it when user tries to load this page.

TRIED: 
1.read that ComponentDidMount is called only after 1st initial render. 
2. {this.invokeservice()} i tried to call in render function before return which did initial render but after 5sec it was blank and then again 5sec later it is filled again with values.

render function

```
public render() {
    return (
        <div className="monitor">
          <div className="monitor__table">                   
            {this.monitorrow(translate("cpu"), this.state.cpuString)}
            {this.monitorrow(translate("memory"), this.state.pmemoryString)}
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cpu: 0,
      cpuString: ""
    };
    setInterval(() => this.invokeservice(), 5000);
  }
```

componentdidMount

```
  public componentDidMount() {
    this.invokeservice();
  }
```

invokeservice

```
private invokeservice() {

    var client = new HttpClient();

    var url = this.props.baseUrl + '//getMonitorUsage' + '?NC=' + Date.now().toString();

    client.get(url, (response) => {
        this.setState({
          cpu: JSONResponse.GetSystemStateResult.CPUusage

        });
      }
    }
    });
  }
```

function

```
monitorrow(left,right) {
    return (
      <div className="table__row">
        <div className="table__cell__left">
          <Text>{left}</Text>
        </div>
        { right &&
          (<div className="table__cell__right">
            <Text>{right}</Text>
          </div>)
        }
      </div>  
    );
  }
```

Comment: *It's only the first time that it returns an null value.*  what exactly is returning `null`?

Comment: first time it returns an initial value which is empty string as defined in constructor this.state.

Answer (score 3):

It is expected.

From the react docs:

> These methods are called in the following order when an instance of a component is being created and inserted into the DOM:

- constructor()
- static getDerivedStateFromProps()
- render()
- componentDidMount()

Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

---

There is `componentWillMount` which will be called before `render()`. But is it not advised to be used. Read more on the official docs https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Comment: so which means i should do the API call in getDerivedStateFromProps() which will fill the value before the render happens. is that correct?

Comment: Since API call is async task, you probably should put a loader or something and not code something like render should be called only after API call finishes.

Comment: @vatz88 but he also called `this.invokerservice()` inside of the constructor

Comment: Yes, that does not matter when you make the API call. API call is aync. You react code is executed synchronously.

Comment: @vatz88 could you provide a small snippet about the loader which you have mentioned.

Comment: @vatz88 and another thing: `this.invokerservice()` calls `setState()` which will definitly cause a rerender

Comment: yes it is async of course but after `setState` the render method should definitly be called again

Comment: Yes, loader was just one solution. If you want, you can check the property of the state if it is present or not and return the render method accordingly. Return null, if the property you need is not present.

Comment: @vatz88 i could check if the state is not empty and once it gets filled with invokeservice, load the left and right side of the whole box.. but then again in intial render for some sec the whole box will be empty right?

Comment: @user28 yes, the user obviously has to wait until you fetch the data